# CLR has been unable to transition from COM context 0x3b2d70 to COM context

Tags: c#

While debugging an application i am getting the following error.

> The CLR has been unable to transition from COM context 0x3b2d70 to COM
>   context 0x3b2ee0 for 60 seconds. The thread that owns the destination
>   context/apartment is most likely either doing a non pumping wait or
>   processing a very long running operation without pumping Windows
>   messages. This situation generally has a negative performance impact
>   and may even lead to the application becoming non responsive or memory
>   usage accumulating continually over time. To avoid this problem, all
>   single threaded apartment (STA) threads should use pumping wait
>   primitives (such as CoWaitForMultipleHandles) and routinely pump
>   messages during long running operations.

Why system throws this error.

Comment: I would suggest you add more detail to your question maybe posting the code that casues the error to happen.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I got the solution

Need to uncheck ContextSwitchDeadlock under Debug->Exceptions->Managed Debugging Assistants.

After unchecking ContextSwitchDeadlock its not throwing the error.

Comment: Yes, because VS **hides** it. This doesn't mean the problem is gone!

Comment: @odyodyodys I'm particularly glad I didn't hide the exception because the issue that produces the exception was causing my app to wait for 60 seconds during the splash screen for no apparent reason. You can't fix bugs you can't find.

Comment: Only thing worse than not knowing why something is **not** working is not knowing why something **is** working.

Comment: @Harry because the OP answered their own question and accepted it.

Comment: oh yes ops, failed to see that HA @TomRedfern

Comment: It's also the only answer given within a week.  I have similar issue, occurs when calling .NET framework stuff that wraps Win32 unmanaged code.  Not much you can do about I guess.