# c# Win Form - The CLR has been unable to transition from COM context

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, multithreading, c#-3.0

**SQL version** : SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard Edition
**Application** : .Net 3.5 (Windows Form)

This is the error i am receiving after running my code

> The CLR has been unable to transition from COM context 0xe88270 to COM context 0xe88328 for 60 seconds. The thread that owns the destination context/apartment is most likely either doing a non pumping wait or processing a very long running operation without pumping Windows messages. This situation generally has a negative performance impact and may even lead to the application becoming non responsive or memory usage accumulating continually over time. To avoid this problem, all single threaded apartment (STA) threads should use pumping wait primitives (such as CoWaitForMultipleHandles) and routinely pump messages during long running operations.

Following code produces the above error **sometimes**. Most probably after 24,000+ records have been inserted it gives the error.

**Objective of the code**
The code is written to insert dummy entry to test my application

```
Random rnd = new Random();

string Data = "";

for (int i = 0; i < 2000000; i++)
{
      Data = "Insert Into Table1(Field1)values('" + rnd.Next(0, 200000000) + "');" + Environment.NewLine +
             "Insert Into Table1(Field1)values('" + rnd.Next(0, 200000000) + "');" + Environment.NewLine +
             "Insert Into Table1(Field1)values('" + rnd.Next(0, 200000000) + "');" + Environment.NewLine +
             "Insert Into Table1(Field1)values('" + rnd.Next(0, 200000000) + "');" + Environment.NewLine +
             "Insert Into Table1(Field1)values('" + rnd.Next(0, 200000000) + "');" + Environment.NewLine +
             "Insert Into Table1(Field1)values('" + rnd.Next(0, 200000000) + "');";
      ExecuteQuery(Data);//Error is displayed here
}
```

Code of "ExecuteQuery"

```
SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection("Connection String");

if (Conn == null)
{
      Conn = new SqlConnection(Program.ConnString);
}
if (Conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
{
      Conn.Open();
}
else
{
      Conn.Close();
      Conn.Open();
}

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = Conn;
cmd.CommandTimeout = 600000;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = strsql;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
Conn.Close();
```

**Note** :- I have written multiple insert statements that are exact same in the query that is because it will reduce the no. of queries the SQL has to handle

**Question**
How can i optimize my code to prevent the error from occuring?

Comment: use back ground thread, do all this in SQL query , not in c# code

Comment: @viveknuna i want this to work as fast as it can and i don't mind waiting in front of the screen that is why i used the main thread to do it.

Comment: Try to run query in sql server at run execution plan, see where your query is taking time

Comment: Don't use indexs much, check for lock

Comment: 1) There is no problem with insert query the problem is just that i am running it in the software instead of running it in SQL (and i need to run it in the software). 2) I didnt get your second solution

Comment: Make this asynchronous call, using async and await

Comment: can you please add an answer with the code because i still cant figure that out

Comment: u can use SqlBulkCopy

Comment: Is this a debugger warning rather than an error? I don't see any COM references in the code you posted.  Perhaps this answer will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871013/clr-has-been-unable-to-transition-from-com-context-0x3b2d70-to-com-context

Answer (score 2):

> *"The CLR has been unable to transition from COM context … to COM context … for 60 seconds. The thread that owns the destination context/apartment is most likely either doing a non pumping wait or processing a very long running operation without pumping Windows messages."*

It is not entirely clear from your question how your code works in detail, so I will assume that your application is not multithreaded, i.e. the loop performing 2×6 million database `INSERT`s is running on the application's main (UI) thread. This will probably take a while (> 60 seconds), so your UI will freeze in the meantime (i.e. make it non-responsive). This is because Windows Forms never gets a chance to run and react to user input while your (blocking) loop is still running. And I bet this is what causes the warning you've cited.

### Use a parameterized SQL command instead.

The first easy thing you could do is turn your `SqlCommand` into a parameterized one. You would then issue commands with the identical SQL text; only the separately provided parameters would differ:

```
private void InsertRandomNumbers(int[] randomNumbers)
{
    const string commandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.Table1 (Field1) VALUES (@field1);"
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection))
    {
        var field1Parameter = new SqlDataParameter("@field1", SqlDbType.Int);
        command.Parameters.Add(field1Parameter);
        connection.Open();
        foreach (int randomNumber in randomNumbers)
        {
            field1Parameter.Value = randomNumber;
            /* int rowsAffected = */ command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Note how `commandText` is defined as a constant. This is a good indication that SQL Server will also recognise it as always the same command — with parameterized commands, the actual parameter values are provided separately — and SQL Server will only compile and optimize the statement once (and put the compiled statement in its cache so it can be reused subsequently) instead of doing the same thing over and over again. This alone should save a lot of time.

### Long-running operations should be asynchronous so your UI doesn't freeze.

Another thing you can do is to shift the database code to a background thread, so that your application's UI won't freeze.

Let's assume that your database `INSERT` loop is currently triggered by a button `doWorkButton`. So the `for` loop is inside a button `Click` event handler:

```
private void doWorkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    …
    for (i = 0; i < 2000000; i++)
    {
        Data = …
        ExecuteQuery(Data);
        // note: I leave it as an exercise to you to combine the
        // above suggestion (parameterized queries) with this one.
    }
}
```

The first thing we do is to change your `ExecuteQuery` method in three ways:

1. Make it asynchronous. Its return type will be `Task` instead of `void`, and its declaration is augmented with the `async` keyword.
2. Rename it to `ExecuteNonQueryAsync` to reflect two things: that it will now be asynchronous, and that it doesn't perform *queries*. We don't actually expect to get back a result from the database `INSERT`s.
3. We rewrite the method body to use of ADO.NET asynchronous methods instead of their synchronous counterparts.

This is what it might end up looking like:

```
private async Task ExecuteNonQueryAsync(string commandText)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection))
    {
        connection.Open();
        /* int rowsAffected = */ await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

That's it. Now we need to modify the handler method to make it asynchronous as well:

```
private async void doWorkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        …
        for (i = 0; i < 2000000; i++) { … }
        {
            Data = …
            await ExecuteNonQueryAsync(Data);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        … // do not let any exceptions escape this handler method
    }
}
```

This should take care of the UI freezing business.

### Millions of `INSERT` statements can be done more efficiently with `SqlBulkCopy`.

SQL Server has this wonderful option for bulk inserting data. Making use of this feature often results in much better performance that doing your own batches of `INSERT` statements.

```
private async void doWorkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Prepare the data to be loaded into your database table.
    // Note, this could be done more efficiently.
    var dataTable = new DataTable();
    {
        dataTable.Columns.Add("Field1", typeof(int));
        var rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 12000000; ++i)
        {
            dataTable.Rows.Add(rnd.Next(0, 2000000));
        }
    }

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
    {
        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.Table1";
        try
        {
            // This will perform a bulk insert into the table
            // mentioned above, using the data passed in as a parameter.
            await bulkCopy.WriteToServerAsync(dataTable);
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot test right now, but I hope this will get you started. If you want to improve the `SqlBulkCopy`-based solution further, I suggest that you create a custom implementation of `IDataReader` that creates "rows" containing the random data on-the-fly, then you pass an instance of that to `SqlBulkCopy` instead of a pre-populated data table. This means that you won't have to keep a huge data table in memory, but only one data row at a time.